# check if master record date in table A is later than latest records date in joined table B

Tags: mysql

I have a master table **people**

**people** fields: Id,AlterationDate

And an actions table **actions** in a one to many linkage

**actions** fields: Id, PeopleID, CreationDate

I want to find all records in **people** whose alteration dates are later than the latest creation date in **actions** joined by the persons id.

MySQL is the dialect, Dates are DateTime fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select people.* from people  
join actions on actions.peopleID = people.id  
group by people.id  
having max(action.CreationDate) < people.AlterationDate
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select p.peopleid 
from actions a 
inner join people p on p.peopleid = a.peopleid 
group by p.peopleid 
having max (a.creationdate) < p.alterationdate
```